How to tell a function call has left the call stack
I am writing a Frontend Logger application and in simple terms, this will be a small library that can be used in other applications. As part of this library, I want to build a smart function where when a function in the application calls the logger.fnStart, This call returns access to a scoped logger class that can be used to make Logs in that function execution, and the Logger should have a way to detect that the function that was started returned without calling a fnEnd. In this case, the Logger itself shall call fnEndNotCalled with details of the function.
I have tried several variations of solving this problem, but I don't want to have to add extra boilerplate to every application function just so I can get it to work with the Logger. So I didn't like solutions that forced me to use logger as a wrapper function or add try...finally to every other function.
I would like to use something that can sniff for when the object memory has been cleaned and then check if the fnEnd was called for that object. Here is one of my most recent attempts to achieve it, but I can't seem to get it working still.


class ScopedLogger {
  constructor(functionName, registry) {
    this.functionName = functionName;
    this.isFnEndCalled = false;

    // Create a weak reference to this object and register it for garbage collection
    const weakRef = new WeakRef(this);
    this.registry = registry;
    this.weakRef = weakRef;

    // Register the weak reference in the FinalizationRegistry
    this.registry.register(weakRef, functionName);
    
    console.log(`fnStart called for ${functionName}`);
  }

  fnEnd() {
    if (!this.isFnEndCalled) {
      const deref = this.weakRef.deref(); // Dereference the weak reference
      if (deref) {
        this.isFnEndCalled = true;
        console.log(`fnEnd called for ${this.functionName}`);
        // Unregister from FinalizationRegistry to prevent error logging
        this.registry.unregister(this);
      } else {
        console.error(`Error: Function context for ${this.functionName} was already garbage collected.`);
      }
    }
  }
}

class Logger {
  constructor() {
    // FinalizationRegistry to track when ScopedLogger is garbage collected
    this.registry = new FinalizationRegistry((functionName) => {
      console.error(`Error: Function "${functionName}" left the call stack without calling fnEnd.`);
    });
  }

  static getInstance() {
    if (!Logger.instance) {
      Logger.instance = new Logger();
    }
    return Logger.instance;
  }

  fnStart(functionName) {
    // Initialize and return a ScopedLogger instance for this function
    return new ScopedLogger(functionName, this.registry);
  }
}

// Singleton instance of Logger
const logger = Logger.getInstance();


function myFunction() {
  // Call fnStart to get a ScopedLogger instance
  let scopedLogger = logger.fnStart("myFunction");

  // Function logic here
  console.log("Doing something...");

  // Uncomment the next line to avoid garbage collection error
  // scopedLogger.fnEnd(); 

 
}

// Call the function
myFunction();

// Force garbage collection (for testing, this would happen non-deterministically)
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Waiting for garbage collection...");
}, 1000);




Please use a Stack Snippet instead of a link to jsfiddle.

Google "javascript finalizers".

"use logger as a wrapper function or add try...finally" - that's exactly what you should do when you want to know exactly when a function call has left the call stack.

"sniff for when the object memory has been cleaned" - for that, you'd use a FinalizationRegistry exactly like you did. It seems your "most recent attempt" works as expected, what is the problem?

@Bergi I expect that at some point i'll get the log console.error(Error: Function "${functionName}" left the call stack without calling fnEnd.); but I don't get it.

@DANIELSSEJJEMBA You do get it - when garbage collection happens. That may be late, that may be never. It's unlikely in your snippet since there's not much memory pressure; but you can force it via the devtools if you want to test it.

@Bergi I also just noticed that the log shows up when I am not using JSFiddle which is confusing given all of these seem to be running same JS engine implementations for the FinalisationRegistry.
